# Is there a better or more concise way to do this?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

My goal was to make a list dynamically list itself into two columns, no matter the length of the list. I would really like to hear from people who know more about JavaScript and jQuery than I do if this code looks good or if there is a better or more concise method for implementing this sort of thing.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/mkimitch/ZEL5x/12/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: CSS3 supports proper column support: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: Will jQuery be able to help non-CSS3 browsers display the code properly? Kind of like how it works when using `:nth-child` selectors?

Comment: Already [cross-posted to Code Review.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/is-there-a-better-or-more-concise-way-to-do-this)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just float them?

```
li {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

No javascript needed. 
unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something regarding the special properties of `ul` tags with floated `li` nodes, be sure to slap on a good `clearfix` on the container element as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/304588

Comment: Floated `li` nodes will produce columns that look like this:

`1  2`
`3  4`
`5  6`

Whereas I was trying to get it to display like this:

`1  4`
`2  5`
`3  6`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to use javascript for that. You can do this with pure css.

If a user has disabled javascript, your code will not run.

#### Sample

```
ul.twocolumn {
width: 400px;
}

ul.twocolumn li {
width: 190px;
float: left;
}
```

### [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEL5x/13/)

Comment: Yes, but you see how the columns are no longer in alphabetical order, at least vertically? That was what I was trying to achieve. If JavaScript is disabled, it displays as just a simple list, nothing really breaks.